# Fields of record from oldMap differs from fields from query

Tags: apex, trigger, person-accounts

I have a really strange issue. I have a trigger that sends email to previous owner when owner is changed. I pass Account.Name to this email to show what email was changes. But it's being passed as null always even if it is not null. I checked, and in OldMap(and in newMap either) my Account.Name is null. But if I write for example a query to the same account in the same method, it will return expected Name. What is the cause of this issue? Why Trigger gives me not right values of variables?
My code :

```
public static void sendEmailsToPreviousOwners(Map<Id, Account> newMap, Map<Id, Account> oldMap) {   
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messagesList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Map<Account,Id> accountToOwnerId = new Map<Account,Id>();
    String emailAdress;
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email;
    String accountUrl;
    User newUser;
    String newUserUrl;
    String emailBody;
    Set<Id> ownersIds = new Set<Id>();
    
    for(Account account : oldMap.values()) {
        if(account.OwnerId != newMap.get(account.Id).OwnerId) {
            accountToOwnerId.put(account, account.OwnerId);
        }
    }

    Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>(queryUsersByUserIds(new Set<Id>(accountToOwnerId.values())));
    String url = String.valueOf(System.URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm());

    for(Account account : accountToOwnerId.keySet()) {
        emailAdress = users.get(account.OwnerId).Email;
        email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        accountUrl = url + '/' + account.Id;
        newUser = queryUsersByUserIds(new Set<Id>{newMap.get(account.Id).OwnerId})[0];
        newUserUrl = url + '/' + newUser.Id;
        emailBody = 
            ACCOUNT_EMAIL_TO_PREVIOUS_OWNER_GREETING + '<br><br>' + 
            String.format(
                ACCOUNT_EMAIL_TO_PREVIOUS_OWNER_CHANGED_TO,
                new String[] { accountUrl, account.Name, newUserUrl, newUser.Name }
            ) + '<br><br>' + 
            ACCOUNT_EMAIL_TO_PREVIOUS_OWNER_END;    
        email.setSubject(ACCOUNT_EMAIL_TO_PREVIOUS_OWNER_SUBJECT);
        email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{ emailAdress });
        email.setHtmlBody(emailBody);
        messagesList.add(email);
    }

    if (!messagesList.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            Messaging.sendEmail(messagesList);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to post some code so as to get proper help, please update your question.

Comment: @Raul was done!

Comment: When you say you checked, did you test what was actually in the acocunt on the map or did you check the email body you were creating? I can't see any reason why the field would be null there, so I wonder if it's the processing of String.format() that's causing the issue. What is `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_TO_PREVIOUS_OWNER_CHANGED_TO`defined as?

Comment: @MattLacey I debuged the newMap and oldMap and there Name was null. Then I debuged this account from query in the same method, and there name was not null.

Comment: Are you using person accounts at all? Wondering if FirstName and LastName are populated instread

Comment: @MattLacey yes I use person accounts. In one from example only FirstName is populated. Anyway I can't understand why Name attribute is different in Trigger and in query.

Comment: I don't know why it'd be different between the two but it is a calculated field - LastName will always be populated on Person Account records so that'd provide a workaround. Be good to know what's actual going on there though